# How to display the same nodes with two different themes?

Tags: 7, theming

I have some content types normally displayed with the default theme of my site.

Now, I want to show such content types also in another section that is displayed with another theme and layout.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: "Best" from what perspective?

Comment: ok, let's say the simplest to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes simplest way to do it is using [Themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. See the demo config for article type nodes. [image]